# How do I determine why emacs indented a certain amount?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In Emacs I'm editing some source code, and I hit <tab>.   Emacs indents the line to n spaces.  I'd like to change the amount that indents for that kind of line.  How do I figure out what rule emacs applied to indent that line by n spaces?

I want to change n, but I need to figure out which of the many indentation-related variables Emacs just used.

Comment: probably not the best way, but you could do C-h k <tab> to see what function is being called in the mode you're in when you hit tab, and see if you can get the variable from there

Comment: Not an answer, but try `M-x apropos RET <part-of-name> RET`. I'll suggest try to look through `offset` keyword. I think it could be one variable per every major mode.

Comment: In order to answer this question, you need to specify what mode the file is in (C++, perl, Tcl, Java, R, text, etc. etc. etc.).  @spike has a good first step, but it's very likely the mode will further refine what function is bound to the `<tab>` key (if it's a general indentation function).

Comment: @TreyJackson I tried it in ruby-mode and was able to find the variable (buried in the function the mode defines), but I agree it isn't a perfect answer

Comment: @spike I meant no disrespect (I had even upvoted the comment), I just want the OP to provide more data b/c the key may not be enough information.  For example, in some modes my TAB key is bound to `pabbrev-expand-maybe` which does auto-completion if appropriate, and if not appropriate, the command falls back to doing the original binding (indentation).  In that case, coming back with the binding for `<tab>` doesn't really help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a mode based on cc-mode (e.g. c-mode, c++-mode, java-mode, etc.), you can hit <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd> and it'll tell you what syntactic category the line is.  If you want to change it, hit <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd> and you'll be guided through the process.  Check out the cc-mode docs on customization for more details: https://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Customizing-Indentation.html

Answer (score 6):

A generic answer is difficult. Some modes will make this more apparent than others, but in the general case (as they are free to implement indentation however they wish) I don't think you'll get away from needing to read some elisp.

Starting with the binding for <kbd>TAB</kbd> will work, but might be slightly time-consuming depending on how many layers of indirection are involved.

If you know that the major mode in question implements its own indentation, then one (non-rigorous, but fast) approach that you could try to help track down the functions being called is to use ELP, the built in elisp profiler. `elp-instrument-package` will instrument for profiling all functions with names matching the prefix string argument you specify. Therefore you might do something like the following in a PHP file (noting that php-mode tells you that it is derived from c-mode)

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `elp-instrument-package` <kbd>RET</kbd> `php-` <kbd>RET</kbd>
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `elp-instrument-package` <kbd>RET</kbd> `c-` <kbd>RET</kbd>
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `elp-instrument-package` <kbd>RET</kbd> `indent` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Now type <kbd>TAB</kbd> in your source code, and run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `elp-results` to see which of those instrumented functions were called.

At this point you're on your own -- look for the likely suspects, and see what the code is doing -- but it can be a handy way to filter the search.

Once you've finished, use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `elp-restore-all` to prevent any further profiling.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to enjoy getting your hands really dirty, there's always the elisp debugger to tell you just what Emacs is up to.

If you hit `C-h k TAB` you'll find the function that Emacs is running (e.g. `indent-for-tab-command`) then you can do `M-x debug-on-entry RET indent-for-tab-command RET`.  Now whenever you hit `TAB` you'll pop up a debugger and can watch the execution step by step.

Depending on your taste for debugging, it's either a maddening or enlightening experience.  Either way, don't forget to `M-x cancel-debug-on-entry` when you're done.